# Submit a form in a preview Fancybox window (with TinyMCE troubles...)

Tags: forms, tinymce, fancybox, submit

I'd like to submit a form in a [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net) window for previewing purpose; this doesn't look so difficult, since a simple

```
$('#preview').fancybox({
    ajax: {
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#form1').serialize()
    }
});
```

Could do the job...
But things are never so easy, and a [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com) editor (jQuery version) adds trouble
I found out that the above code doesn't send the updated textarea content (don't know why), so it's unuseful for preview

I ended up with this:

```
$('#preview').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).fancybox({
        ajax: {
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#form1').serialize()
        }
    });
})
```

That do the job, but only if I click twice che #preview anchor
Seems that the first click "updates" the textarea content, and the second click opens the Fancybox

Well, have you got better solutions? I googled around, but seems there's nothing for "submit a form in a preview fancybox window"...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Ivan, a little question - how it's your way to call a link? I'm trying to pass data, and I can't do this to iframe, only to new blank page. When I'm trying to pass to iframe I'm occuring an error "The requested content cannot be loaded."

Comment: Hi kacper, this is an old post and I don't remember how and if I solved this or tried another way (I do not remember also the site I was working on)... sorry

Answer (score 0):

You request the textarea content, but the content does not seem to be up-to-date.
This is because the tinymce editor content is not inside the textarea but inside a contenteditable iframe. The former textarea is hidden. To update the hidden textarea you can use tinymce.triggerSave()

```
$('#preview').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    tinymce.triggerSave();
    $(this).fancybox({
        ajax: {
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#form1').serialize()
        }
    });
})
```

or get the tinymce content directly from the editor

```
$('#preview').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).fancybox({
        ajax: {
            type: "POST",
            data: tinymce.get('form1').getContent();
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Thariama, but none of these works; in the first, I have the "double click" problem (the fancybox is launched on the second click), in the second, even if I removed the final ";", I get no fancybox and the page opens in the self window...